# <img src= url> Not showing image on index.php

Tags: php, html

I used following code on index.php and it is 100% working on localhost, but not appear image on live server "www.chitthu.co".

```
  <div class="block">
  <img src="/img/step-1.png" style="width:20%; height:20%; margin:5px;">
    <h3>Join Chitthu</h3>
    <p>
      Signing up takes two
      minutes <br>to get a Chitthu account.
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you uploaded the image on live server? if so, check the folder permission.

Comment: check path max path is mismatch

Comment: do you follow your directory structure?

Comment: www.chitthu.co/img/step-1.png open it

Comment: Folder and images permission are 775. And it is located in the Root html/img/step-1.png. I think nothing wrong. I also try with full url"http://www.chitthu.co/img/step-1.png" still out of luck. How should I set the directory structure?

Comment: U just need to check answers given below

Comment: And choose the best answer and mark as accepted by click on the left tick. This will help to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your directory :

```
www.chitthu.co/img/
```

You don't have this image:

```
www.chitthu.co/img/step-1.png
```

You have:

```
www.chitthu.co/img/Step-1.png
```

Your directory:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is working now.. Look like it is case sensitive.

Comment: ist a good approach to save all possible asset image etc. files and folders in lowercase an without special chars .. so you can use this for web without any issues.

Comment: ...and no spaces in filenames!

Comment: @sdexp yes space between the file name makes problem in url

Answer (score 3):

**s**tep-1 to **S**tep-1.

It seems that your server is `case sensitive`, which means `S` and `s` is very different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Step-1 http://www.chitthu.co/img/Step-1.png](http://www.chitthu.co/img/Step-1.png)

```
<img src="http://www.chitthu.co/img/Step-1.png" alt="Step-1"/>
```